# How to implement sliding menu like facebook and gmail in android

Tags: android

I have implemented a navigation drawer menu in android but it does not look like the facebook and gmail menu. Can anybody tell me how to implement a menu like facebook gmail in android?

I also want a sliding effect like facebook and gmail.

Thanks

Comment: Question is similar asking "How to make a good app"

Comment: see http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/ and https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu and please search first

Answer (score 2):

The thing you are using is navigation drawer, but you have to use **menu drawer**
for the menu like facebook and gmail.

I have implemented it and [this link will help you to do so](http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/03/android-sliding-menu-navigation-drawer.html).  That will tell you all the steps for making menu drawer.

Comment: i didn't get any example from the link

Comment: I edited my answer now you can find the link...

Answer (score 1):

[image: gmail like navigation menu]

[here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/) is the best tutorial for create gmail like navigation menu. I guess it will solve your question

[image: facebook like navigation drawer]

[here is the link](http://www.androidviews.net/2012/10/androiddrawer/) for facebook like navigation drawer

Comment: I want the sliding the menu  also look like facebook and gamil

Comment: here is the gmail one

Comment: I have edited my answer.. hope you will enjoy this @mohan

Comment: .I want sliding effect also look like gmail and facebook

Comment: no it is not available sliding effect

Comment: go to the given link and take some time to implement and see :)